# Scrape data from website using Simple_HTML_Dom.php

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

Using `simple_html_dom.php`, I'm trying to scrape the available sizes from the website of a friend. Unfortunately, I'm not succeeding with extracting as much as a single size, since I don't understand what the correct selection critirium would be.

In the below example I would like to extract "110", as it's the only available size. I tried with extracting labels, but then I guess I'd have to include the next criterium, which should be the value for the element_id: "for" - that starts with "attribute 6" Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="sizeSelector" class="cf">
  <div class="titleHeader cf">
    <p class="text">
      <h2>Choose a Size</h2>
      <h2 id="print-size" style="display:none;">Sizes available</h2>
      <label for="attribute76">
         <input id="attribute76" class="jshide" type="radio" value="76" name="super_attribute[144]">
110
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried and that doesn't work.  Then explain what isn't working, and what you expected you would get.

Comment: Question is not clear enough, please clearify, usually you would run a loop through the elements you want, from what you posted, I suggest using a selector like `"#attribute$id"`

Comment: @AndyLester, none of the things I tried came even close to a solution. So I'm not sure it'll help much. For some reason I can't even get the size for the disabled products, which have a class ".disabled" which I can select. I CAN however select all other data from the website, so my general approach must be OK. Example of the disabled product sizes: `<label class="disabled" for="attribute75">
<span class="crossedStock"> </span>
<input id="attribute75" class="jshide" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="75" name="super_attribute[144]">
105
</label>`

Comment: `$element = $html->find('div .titleHeader label', 0);`
seems to work!

Comment: Which doesn't solve the problem, as I want to only return the ones that don't have the class "disabled".

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the labels and check whether the input is disabled or not:

```
foreach ($html->find('#sizeSelector label') as $e)
{   if ( $e->find('input[disabled]') )
    {   // $e is the <label> element, $e->plaintext gets the text content
        echo "Input " . $e->plaintext . " is disabled.\n";
    }
    else
    {   echo "Input " . $e->plaintext . " is enabled.\n";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, trying to select labels that don't have the class disabled, using `find('label[class!=disabled]')` appears to automatically dismiss all labels without a class. You could query for labels without a class, `find('label[!class]')`, but you risk excluding labels that have some other class.